# What's the point of iter_swap?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, swap, argument-dependent-lookup

I was just wondering, why would anybody write this:

```
std::iter_swap(i, k);
```

instead of this?

```
std::swap(*i, *k);   // saved a few keystrokes!
```

Then I looked into the implementation of `iter_swap`, and of course it only uses `swap` instead of `std::swap` since we're already in `namespace std`, anyway. That leads me to the next question:

Why would anybody write this:

```
using std::swap;
swap(a, b);
```

instead of this?

```
std::iter_swap(&a, &b);   // saved an entire line of code!
```

Are there any important differences/issues I am overlooking here?

Comment: Saving code may be worthwhile (reduced complexity is easier to reason about)... but saving *lines* of code?  Utterly useless, often counter-productive.

Comment: No no no, you need to do `using std::iter_swap; iter_swap(i, k);` because `iter_swap` might have been specialized. (Just kidding. I think.)

Comment: You have looked into *one* implementation of `iter_swap`, but why do you assume it cannot be implemented with `std::swap`?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes It's specified to use ADL properly. (17.6.3.2)

Comment: Oh, don't mind me then. Curry on.

Comment: Similar Q, more in-depth answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14024228/153285

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From the SGI docs ([here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/iter_swap.html)):

> [1] Strictly speaking, iter_swap is redundant. It exists only for technical reasons: in some circumstances, some compilers have difficulty performing the type deduction required to interpret swap(*a, *b).

Answer (score 12):

To answer your second question, the `using` + `swap` allows the compiler to use user-defined swap functions that may be more efficient than the default implementation (by using ADL). Explicitly saying `std::swap` inhibits ADL and any custom swap methods it maybe have been able to find.

As for `iter_swap` it's presumably there to use in templates and clearly indicate intention rather than a swap that might indicate you expect a pointer.

Comment: Oh I neglected this because I'm absolutely convinced Fred knows about ADL and std::swap idioms :)

Comment: There is no `std::swap` invocation in my second question. My point was that `std::iter_swap` will also pick up user-defined swaps, without having to write a `using` statement. Right?

Comment: @FredOverflow: But not user-defined `iter_swap`s ;)