# Why/when should we prefer using std::swap; swap(a, b) over std::iter_swap(&a, &b)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, swap, argument-dependent-lookup

Why/when should we prefer `using std::swap; swap(a, b);` over `std::iter_swap(&a, &b)`?

Comment: @T.C.: lol, fair enough, but any other cases? (But feel free to post that as an answer...)

Comment: I'd think you should almost always "prefer" it for the readability benefit

Comment: Can you actually put your question in your question, it's hard to parse that "using" is the keyword using, not the actual word

Comment: Also didn't you ask almost this question two years ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024228/iter-swap-versus-swap-whats-the-difference

Comment: @Barry: It's not the same question... it didn't occur to me that I might be able to use `iter_swap` instead of `swap` back then. And okay sure.

Comment: @happydave: It's a fair answer, feel free to post it...

Comment: @Mehrdad.  Well, after I wrote the comment, I started having second thoughts.  The extra using statement is non-obvious in itself, so my comment may just reflect the bias of my own experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 years later, but I believe the only technical concern would be if `operator &()` is overloaded.
If not, the only other reason I see would be readability.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are completely different your question is a false dichotomy.

They do different things!

- One swaps value.
- The other swaps the content of the destination of iterator.

But if you have iterators. It is probably better to use `std::iter_swap`. Otherwise you can use swap (as long as you have done the `using std::swap;` locally to the call to swap (otherwise the type dependent lockup for the correct swap may fail).

```
std::iter_swap(i1, i2);

// Is equivelent to writing.
using std::swap;  // Notice this. 
swap(*i1 ,*i2);   // Notice the * in front of the iterator.
```

Comment: Nope, they cannot do different things as far as I can tell (barring an overloaded `&`); the standard mandates that the latter must have the same effects as the former.

Comment: @Mehrdad: They definitely do completely different things.

Comment: Can you give an example of when the type dependent lookup can fail? And no, they can't do different things... can you give an example of when they do different things?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Read my answer. One deference the iterator the other does not. How much more different do you want.

Comment: Are you sure you read my question carefully? The code in your answer is not the same as the one I asked about.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the standard mandates that

```
std::iter_swap(&a, &b);
```

has the an effect equivalent to

```
using std::swap;
swap(*(&a), *(&b));
```

whereas it may be implemented differently. (at least g++ and msvc just swap...)

Knowing that, I'd consider

```
using std::swap;
swap(a, b);
```

to be more specific, direct and readable as it expresses the desired, adl-enabled behaviour directly.

If you have iterators in the first place, then I'd stick to ADL-enabled `iter_swap`:

```
using std::iter_swap;
iter_swap(it_a, it_b);
```

The reason here would be that I get two chances of outperforming (or outsmarting) default `std::swap`:

1. The implementor of the container the iterators came from may have provided an overload for `iter_swap` for those iterators, which is smarter (and possibly even more appropriate<sup>1</sup>) than a plain value swap.
2. The implementor of the class refered to by the iterator may have provided the `swap` overload to efficiently swap both elements.

If (1) is not the case I may get (2) and only if both options do not apply `std::swap` is used and moves (or in case of a non-moveable type copies) the objects around to swap them.

*Note that std-algorithms using `iter_swap` do not adl-enable the call.*

<sup>1</sup> *May apply to special iterator (ranges) which do not directly represent objects (i.e. zip-ranges).*

Comment: There is no practically useful way to achieve the effect of `swap` without actually calling `swap`... that's why it ended up being redundant and unused.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Actually we're missing something like `iter_move` as well to make `iter_swap` a really useful customization point but it could well be used that way.

Answer (score -1):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap

**Possible implementation**

```
template<class ForwardIt1, class ForwardIt2>
void iter_swap(ForwardIt1 a, ForwardIt2 b)
{
   using std::swap;
   swap(*a, *b);
}
```

Given that, I think

```
using std::swap;
swap(a,b);
```

is better than

```
using std::iter_swap;
iter_swap(&a, &b);
```

The first one involves less typing and more to the point.

Comment: Wrong for any specific use case(s)?

Comment: You need to use argument-dependent lookup, otherwise it won't look up any user-defined `swap` via ADL.

Comment: @Mehrdad, I need to dig deeper into that. It's not obvious to me.

Comment: @Barry: `std::swap(a,b);` is most definitely *not* using ADL. (Are you looking at the right thing?)

Comment: @Barry: No! Did you read the actual *answer*? It says *"Given that, I would think
`std::swap(a,b);` seems better than `std::iter_swap(&a, &b);`"* The first one and the second one are not equivalent.

Comment: @R Sahu: Yeah, it's not very obvious, but `using std::swap; swap(a, b);` is not equivalent to `std::swap(a, b);`.

Comment: @Mehrdad, that definitely surprises me. If you can point to something for further reading, I'd appreciate it.