# std::iter_swap requires ValueSwappable args vs std::swap requires Move Assignable args

Tags: c++, c++11, swap, move-semantics

I am having difficulty in understanding why direct call to `std::swap()` in below code results in compilation error whereas using `std::iter_swap` compiles without any error.

From [`iter_swap()` versus `swap()` -- what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024228/iter-swap-versus-swap-whats-the-difference), `iter_swap` finally calls `std::swap` but still their behavior is different.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class IntVector {
    std::vector<int> v;
    IntVector& operator=(IntVector); // not assignable
public:
    void swap(IntVector& other) {
        v.swap(other.v);
    }
};
void swap(IntVector& v1, IntVector& v2) {
    v1.swap(v2);
}

int main()
{
    IntVector v1, v2;
//  std::swap(v1, v2); // compiler error! std::swap requires MoveAssignable
    std::iter_swap(&v1, &v2); // OK: library calls unqualified swap()
}
```

Comment: source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Swappable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `swap` called inside `iter_swap` is *not* fully qualified i.e not called as `std::swap` but just as `swap`. Therefore, during name lookup and `ADL` compiler finds multiple functions which matches with the call to `swap`. But, the `overload resolution` selects the `swap` provided by you since it matches best.

If you use `swap` in your main code, then it would compile fine as it would not find `std::swap`. It will compile even if you do `using namespace std;`

Comment: things like `swap`, `begin`, `size`... should be called unqualified, with `std::` version brought in current scope with using-declaration. Qualified call to those should be threated as bug on any code review.