# Why does std::swap require something different than std::iter_swap?

Tags: c++

I know that `std::swap` requires MoveAssignable (which iterswap does not) but why does it require something different than `std::iterswap` when they really are almost identical? I mean, I cannot see why they have different requirements - what makes up the need for this difference?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024228/iter-swap-versus-swap-whats-the-difference) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991909/whats-the-point-of-iter-swap), however, they did not yield an answer to this question (at least not to me).

Comment: It might be helpful to remind people what those different requirements are...

Comment: std::swap is **the** standard swap function, while std::iter_swap may call either the standard swap or some user's overload, is that the part that's confusing you? There have been discussions of making std::swap call user's overload if it exists, but that's complicated and not necessarily that intuitive either.

Comment: *"The dereferenced values `*a` and `*b` must be "swappable", which implies that `swap(*a, *b)` must be valid,"* sounds pretty clear to me.

Comment: @BaummitAugen can you then please elaborate? How does this explain why std::swap requires MoveAssignable and iterswap does not?

Comment: @step As I quoted, `iter_swap` requires "swappable". As you could have easily looked up, that means that `using std::swap; swap(*a, *b); ` must be valid, which either requires MoveAssignable indirectly if `std::swap` is chosen or whatever requirements the user-provided overload of `swap` imposes otherwise.